# Compare 2 datasets on multiple column criteria and find missing rows

Tags: python, pandas, compare, multiple-columns

I'm willing to compare two datasets:

First:

| Partner | Type | Power | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 15.975 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Sell | 1000 | 43.5 |

Second:

| Partner | Type | Power | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 15.975 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 1 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 2 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Sell | 5 | 19.05 |
| Partner1 | Sell | 5 | 19.06 |
| Partner1 | Sell | 5 | 19.125 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 2 | 19.2 |

My goal is to check which rows from second table are NOT present in first table, BASED on equal values from column 'Type', 'Price' and 'Power'.

```
compcol = ['Type','Power','Price']
missing = second[~second[compcol].isin(first[compcol].to_dict(
        orient='list')).all(axis=1)]
```

Above code does return missing rows that are missing in first table:

| Partner | Type | Power | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Partner1 | Buy | 2 | 18.025 |
| Partner1 | Sell | 5 | 19.05 |
| Partner1 | Sell | 5 | 19.06 |
| Partner1 | Sell | 5 | 19.125 |
| Partner1 | Buy | 2 | 19.2 |

What I want to achieve is to include one additional row of "Partner1 - BUY - 1 - 18.025", that is also missing in first table (second table includes 5 record of that trade with same data, while first table includes only 4!).

How can I achieve that?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Can you give a reproducible example of your two input dataframes by using a code snippet like `df = pd.DataFrame({'Partner': [...], 'Type': [...]}`? Also you should like into the pandas documentation for the `merge` method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of boolean masking,`isin()` method, `all()` method and `Bitwise not operator(~)`:

```
col=['Type','Power','Price']    
result=df2[~df2[col].isin(df1[col]).all(1)]
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
Partner     Type    Power   Price

5   Partner1    Buy     1   18.025
6   Partner1    Buy     2   18.025
7   Partner1    Sell    5   19.050
8   Partner1    Sell    5   19.060
9   Partner1    Sell    5   19.125
10  Partner1    Buy     2   19.200
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've already tried that, but problem is that I cannot mask by all(), but only on 3 columns (Type, Power,Price), because partner can also change.

Comment: Updated my answer kindly have a look...... btw you can still mask by all **:)**

Comment: Thank you, Its working now!
I am concatinating those 2 tables into new table row by row that also includes 3rd row with difference between first 2 rows . Is it possible make a loop that in case of UNMATCHED 1st and 2nd row, it leaves 3rd row blank and goes to next row? My 2 tables can have different lenght.

Comment: you can concat by `result=pd.concat((df1,df2),ignore_index=True)` after that `newres=result.copy()` and find difference between first 2 rows by `newres['Price']=result['Price'].sub(result['Price'].shift(1)).dropna().reset_index(drop=True)`